# MySQL phpMyAdmin error in a simple date query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In MySQL using phpMyAdmin I am trying out this simple query to fetch rows that satisfy a certain date criteria:

```
select * 
from student_invoice
where date_generated < '2012-01-01'
```

The date_generated is of date type. I get an error in phpMyAdmin that says:

```
ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 64 STR: '
```

I have closed all quotes so its not making sense. The phpMyAdmin version is 2.11.9.6

Comment: Clearly, this isn't your real query. I can tell by the fake sounding table and column names. I have a feeling there is something else going on that we're not seeing. Can you paste your real query?

Comment: @dr_rk can you post including the php code?

Comment: I am doing this frm phpMyAdmin and would like to have it working from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a new answer, as it's unrelated to my other one.

According to [this bugzilla post here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=725123), your version suffers from this bug!

Upgrading to 2.11.11 or higher should fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound silly, but have you tried wrapping the date in double quotes?

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometable
WHERE somedatecolumn < "2012-01-01"
```

Comment: Yup this was the first thing I tried. I get `ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 64
STR: "`

Comment: Very strange. Is this a recent issue? Have you done date range checks successfully in the past? You might want to try updating your phpMyAdmin installation if possible.

Comment: I must have at some point surely, but as I normally code in C++ I come back to php for web stuff occasionally. It is weird that this isnt working

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin are you currently running?

Comment: I have put the version in my question. For some reason the version wont appear here in the comment,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that those are actually single quotes surrounding the date, not backticks.

Comment: I checked that. It is all single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the specific error. But you could try casting your static date to a date format, just to make sure it jives with the datecolumn format. Or even casting both? I.e:

```
  where cast(somedatecolumn as DATE) < cast('2012-01-01' as DATE)
```

I have a feeling that won't work though. So maybe this?:

```
  where somedatecolumn < cast('2012-01-01' as DATE)
```

Comment: Nah. That's not necessary in MySQL. This isn't his problem.